# How to send multiple files using dropzone.js with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, simple-form, dropzone.js

Using Rails 4 Paperclip and SimpleForm. 
I'm trying to make a multiple file upload. For this I am using Dropzone.js upon customer request.

It is a form where I have: Name, Address, Phone, Documents, Certificates.

So I created 2 separate dropzones for documents and certificates.

This is my code on the form:

```
= simple_form_for(@user, html: {multipart: true, autocomplete: 'off' }) do |f|
  = f.input :name, label: false # Column name in table User
  = f.input :address, label: false # Column address in table User
  #attachments-documents.dropzone # Column document in table User
  #attachments-certificates.dropzone # Column certificate in table User

:javascript
  var attachments_1 = new Dropzone("div#attachments-documents", { url: "#{upload_file_biddings_path}"});
  var attachments_2 = new Dropzone("div#attachments-certificates", { url: "#{upload_file_path}"});
  Dropzone.options.attachmentsDocuments = {
    paramName: 'user[document]',
    maxFilesize: 20,
    parallelUploads: 3,
    addRemoveLinks : true,
    autoProcessQueue: false
  }

  Dropzone.options.attachmentsCertificates = {
    paramName: 'user[certificate]',
    maxFilesize: 20,
    parallelUploads: 3,
    addRemoveLinks : true,
    autoProcessQueue: false
  }
```

Controller:

```
Class User < ApplicationController
  [...]
  def create
    work = Work.new(work_params)
    if work.save
      flash[:notice] = "Se ha creado correctamente la Obra."
      redirect_to :action => :index
    else
      work.errors.messages.each do |attribute, error|
          puts error.to_s
          puts error
      end
      flash[:error] =  "Ha ocurrido un error en el sistema."
      redirect_to :action => :index
    end
  end

  def update
    work = Work.find(params[:id])
    if work.update_attributes(work_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Se ha actualizado correctamente los datos."
      redirect_to :action => :index
    else
      work.errors.messages.each do |attribute, error|
        flash[:error] =  attribute " " + flash[:error].to_s + error.to_s + "  "
      end
      # Load new()
      @work = work
      render :edit, layout: false
    end
  end

  def upload_file
    puts params
    render :json => params
  end

  private
  def work_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :address, :document, :certificate)
  end
end
```

But here I have 2 problems.

1) When I put a file into the Dropzone, by default calls the "upload_file" function when the files should be uploaded when you click on my submit button and GO to create function.

2) I did a test upload multiple files with another JS, however only managed to climb the last of them. Ie:

I put in my file_field 3 files: file1, file2, file3. But in DB, only recorded the file3.

Has anyone uploaded multiple files with Paperclip? Using JS Dropzone.js or other successfully?

If so, I'd like to share knowledge.